# What are the uses of Penrose diagrams?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, causality

Are [Penrose diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_diagram) just used for a nice visual representation of compactified space and time? Are there any other applications? I figured out how to make my own Penrose diagram, built individually, curve by curve. It's slightly different in its geometry but approximately a Penrose diagram. I didn't use conformal maps, I did it using real functions.

Comment: related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/216298/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a Penrose diagram, I find it extremely difficult to reason about causal relationships in GR. I've seen other people try to do it using various coordinate-based representations, e.g., Kruskal-Szekeres coordinates for the Schwarzschild spacetime, and it seems painful to me.

If you want to define what a black hole is, you kind of need to define null infinity, even if you don't call it that. If you can define null infinity, then you pretty much have a Penrose diagram. This relates to a more general topic called boundary constructions.

When you want to talk about maximal extensions of spacetimes, it really helps to be able to refer to the relevant Penrose diagrams.

Comment: Thanks, so why are Penrose diagrams always shown with the timelike infinity pointing upwards? Is there a way to define the coordinates so that the diagram is rotated 90 degrees so that it resembles a square lying flat on the ground?